How to get the access specifier for a clang::CXXMethodDecl?
I would like to know whether my C++ method is public, protected or private when writing a clang-tidy check. That seems to be a very simple task. But I could not figure out how to solve this, as clang::CXXMethodDecl doesn't provide a method for getting the access specifier. How can I reach it?

Did you miss the getAccess() method inherited from clang::Decl?

C++ access specifiers for declarations are stored in the Decl superclass that CXXMethodDecl inherits, and retrievable by calling getAccess().
An example clang-tidy check that uses getAccess is VirtualClassDestructorCheck.cpp, which has this usage:
  const CXXDestructorDecl *Destructor = Node.getDestructor();
  if (!Destructor)
    return false;

  return (((Destructor->getAccess() == AccessSpecifier::AS_public) &&
           Destructor->isVirtual()) ||
          ((Destructor->getAccess() == AccessSpecifier::AS_protected) &&
           !Destructor->isVirtual()));

(@Botje already answered in a comment.  I am just putting the information in the proper box.)

Both of you are perfectly right, I must have been blind.  Your solution works. :-)
